# DNS SRV record clash

Tags: dns

I'm trying to set up the CNAME and SRV records for our domain to allow Skype for Business to work, as per this article [troubleshooting skype for business](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2566790/troubleshooting-skype-for-business-online-dns-configuration-issues-in)

There is already a SRV record set up as follows
HOST: _autodiscover._tcp.virtualdoctors.org 
PRIORITY: 0
WEIGHT: 10
PORT: 443
TARGET: autodiscover.iomartmail.com.
TTL: 24 hours.

When adding the SRV record for port 443 I get the error message 
Error Response: argument #1 (SRV) is invalid - 3 fields required (WEIGHT, PORT and TARGET) (_sip._tls.virtualdoctors.org - SRV - sipdir.online.lync.com)

I have put in a weight of 1, a port of 443 and a target of sipdir.online.lync.com. The other records seem to be accepted ok?

Many thanks

Comment: What dns provider are you using?

Comment: We're using Easyspace

Answer (score 0):

It seems I don't need the SRV records to get Skype For Business to work. I put in the CNAME records only and that solved it for me.